# Adobe Reader 9 and Adobe Acrobat Reader DC (Wine)

Tags: wine, compatibility, 21.10, adobe-reader, adobe-acrobat

I installed Adobe Reader in Ubuntu 21.04 because it is required for sign-in documents authenticated, e,e E adhar, etc.  Recently I upgraded Ubuntu from 21.04 to 21.10, and I observed that Adobe Reader 9 and Adobe Acrobat Reader DC were working on Ubuntu 21.04, but they are not working anymore after upgrading to 21.10. I tried reinstalling Adobe Acrobat Reader DC, but it shows that it is not compatible with 64-bit and it is compatible with 32-bit.

Comment: Why do you need to install Adobe Reader? Do you need Adobe Reader for filling out forms?

Comment: it required for sign in documents authenticated, e,e E adhar etc

Answer (score 6):

Adobe Acrobat Reader DC can be installed in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu by installing the acrordrdc snap package.

1. Install the acrordrdc snap package.

   ```
   sudo snap install acrordrdc
   ```
2. Launch acrordrdc.

   ```
   acrordrdc
   ```
3. Configuring messages will be shown in the terminal while Wine is configuring for Adobe Reader. Wait for Wine to finish configuring for Adobe Reader. After Wine is finished configuring you will see a red Adobe Reader icon in the Dock and this window will open.

   [image]
4. Select a language for installer download from the dropdown menu and click the *Install* button in the Adobe Acrobat Reader DC window. A small progress bar window will open to show the progress of downloading Adobe Acrobat Reader DC.
5. Launch Adobe Acrobat Reader DC. A red Adobe Reader icon will appear in the Dock when Adobe Acrobat Reader DC is open.

   ```
   acrordrdc
   ```
6. You may need to disable Protected Mode to open Adobe Acrobat Reader DC.

   [image]
7. Press the accept button to accept the Adobe Acrobat Reader DC License Agreement and continue.

   [image]
8. You can auto-fill forms if you sign in to Adobe Acrobat Reader DC as shown in the upper right corner of the below screenshot.

   [image]
9. My current version of Adobe Acrobat Reader DC is 21.007.20091.59174, the latest version. You may have to reinstall the acrordrdc snap package if you upgrade your Ubuntu release to ensure that it is compatible with your upgraded operating system.

   [image]

Comment: I try this this is installed but not work as my PC is 64bit It says it is cofiatable in ubuntu 210.10in  32bit and 64 bit is not supported, I am not an expert in this line

Comment: sorry it would be Ubuntu 21.10

Comment: 64-bit is compatible on my system. As  shown in the last screenshot I installed Acrobat Reader DC version 21 on Ubuntu 20.04 64-bit.

Comment: It works in my case but I have a problem importing a digital signature!!!

Comment: @Ibraheem Since it works in your case, maybe you should ask a separate question about the problem importing a digital signature. I don't need Acrobat on Ubuntu 22.04 because I use LibreOffice Writer, LibreOffice Draw, GIMP and PDF Chain for making PDF documents, and they do a great job.

Comment: Acrobat Reader DC (acrordrdc snap) may launch and you can do stuff. But if you want to save a snapshot under another filename, the Save As dialogue comes up completely blank -- no file tree view, no Save As button, nothing! Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, 64 bit, current snap as of three days ago.