# Acrobat Reader Sign doesn't show anything in the popup window

Tags: wine, playonlinux

I installed Acrobat Reader DC using snap, everything worked well until I tried to "Sign in" because I get an (apparently) empty window like this and thus I cannot proceed:
[image]

Is it an issue with fonts or what?
My environment is:
Ubuntu 21.10
wine-7.5
PlayOnLinux 4.3.4

Thanks in advance
C.

Comment: Hello. Did you install it as a snap or did you install it via Wine? Did you check the Wine web site to verify the app runs under Wine and if there are any notes about using it via Wine?

Comment: I installed via snap and no, I didn't check I followed the steps showed in this link:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1371236/adobe-reader-9-and-adobe-acrobat-reader-dc-wine